# Adding ImageView Causes Error with srcCompat attribute

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have another activity whose layout has RelativeLayout, TextViews and an ImageView...no problems here.

With this other Activity below I have many TextViews and a RelativeLayout. When I add an Imageview, I receive the following errors:

> Error:(190) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in
>   package 'com.example.ftonyan.userposts' Error:(190) No resource
>   identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package
>   'com.example.ftonyan.userposts' Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

The top part of the layout.xml for this problematic activity looks as follows before the imageview is added (the code compiles and runs on the emulator)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

After the imageview is added to the palette the following 2 lines are red (note the 2nd line was added by the system). The code no longer compiles.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Below is my Activity layout.xml. There are approximately 19 textViews in this layout. I did not include all of them for the sake of brevity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAddressees"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblNick"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/nickName"
        android:text="Addressees:" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have read a few posts here recommending a change to the apk/res-auto line. However, that line is not in the file in the first place until the system adds it. So, not sure what I am supposed to do to fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question does not include `srcCompat`, so where does that error come from?

Comment: And do you need `srcCompat`? What is wrong with `android:src`?

Comment: Thanks. I am a newb. I don't know the answer to your question. Where do I look for srcCompat? I did a search in both layout files in the project. Neither had srcCompat...or would that be Java?

Comment: You have said "when you add ImageView"... Please show that code that errors

Comment: I am looking at the problematic layout in design mode. I grab the imageView widget and drop it on the layout. Then when I build and/or run the project I get the above errors. When I then delete the imageView from the layout the project builds and runs again with no errors.

Comment: Again, please post the XML it generates

Comment: Do you want the layout.xml after the error occurs ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141267/discussion-between-frank-zappa-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing this line

```
tools:context="packagename.nameofAttivity">
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

In your project open app level `build.gradle` file add the following lines

```
defaultConfig {
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

And sync your project. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add namespace code for the Imageview

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

The namespace 'schemas.android.com/tools' is for specifying options to build the app by Android Studio, and are not included in the final app package

The namespace 'schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto' is used for all custom attributes - defined in libraries or in code.

Comment: Error:(190) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.example.ftonyan.userposts' Error:(190) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.example.ftonyan.userposts' Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 0):

Check This
[Android image not showing in imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311760/7740742)

In This Post as I have told this ---
...... You should edit srcCompat to src. src is meant for source and sourceCompat Is for Backwards Compatiblity Of Vector Drawable Files For Android Devices Running On and below ICS -- IceCream Sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's no need to add `android:srcCompat` to set default image.

Because `app:srcCompat` is used for backwards compatibility with vector drawables for the support library.

Try `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` or `android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` instead.

But still if you want to use `srcCompat` attribute then just change `android:srcCompat` to `app:srcCompat` in `ImageView`.